# Русская локаль в Heroku

Tags: php, linux, heroku, locale

Хочу чтобы в моём php-скрипте, который лежит на Heroku, в функциях для работы с датой использовалась русская локаль. Для этого её нужно установить на сервер во время сборки. Как это сделать?